# Parsing multiple large JSON files with node to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, mongoose

I am parsing multiple large JSON files to my mongoDB database. At the moment I am using stream-json npm package. After I load one file I change the filename that I am loading and relaunch the script to load the next file. This is unnecessarily time consuming. So how can I iterate through all the files automatically? At the moment my code looks like this:

```
const StreamArray = require('stream-json/utils/StreamArray');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const filename = path.join(__dirname, './data/xa0.json'); //The next file is named xa1.json and so on.

const stream = StreamArray.make();

stream.output.on('data', function (object) {
    // my function block
});

stream.output.on('end', function () {
    console.log('File Complete');
});

fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(stream.input);
```

I tried iterating through the names of the files by adding a loop that would add +1 to the filename i.e. xa0 to xa1 at the same point where the script console.log('File Complete') but this didn't work. Any ideas how I might be able to achieve this or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just scan your JSON files directory using [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback). It will return a list of file names that you can then iterate, something like this :

```
fs.readdir("./jsonfiles", async (err, files) => {
    for( file in files ){
      await saveToMongo("./jsonfiles/" + file)
    }
})
```

So you just launch your script once and wait until full completion.

Of course, in order for it to be awaited, you need to promisify the `saveToMongo` function, something like :

```
const saveToMongo = fileName => {

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

        // ... logic here

        stream.output.on('end', function () {
            console.log('File Complete');
            resolve() // Will trigger the next await
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Whilst it is iterating through the file names without any issues the stream within the saveToMongo block isn't launching/executing. Therefore all the file names are simply iterated through in a second. Within the saveToMongo function block I have got the same code as from `const stream =` downwards in the above example. I also know the filename in the `fs.readCreateReadStream` is available within the block and the same as before i added the iterator. Any ideas why the stream is not executing? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Yes, I have amended my answer and added stuff about Promises

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy Thille !